# How to unzip into a given directory

Tags: bash

I have a list with the path of .zip files, gathered by the command below. I want to unzip them into that directory, where they exist.

```
find . -name "*.zip" -print > outfile.txt
```

outfile.txt is like:

```
./TWO/two.zip
./ONE/one.zip
```

I have `run_all` script to automatize it, but how can I define the output directory?

```
run_all outfile.txt 'unzip -u $1'
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use the `-d` flag.

```
unzip -d output_dir/ zipfiles.zip
```

To automate it:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `cat outfile.txt`; do
    output_dir=$(dirname $i)
    unzip -d $output_dir $i
done
```

---

**EDIT:** As @dessert suggests, you may do this as a better alternative:

```
while IFS='' read -r i || [[ -n "$i" ]]; do unzip -d ${i%/*} $i; done <outfile.txt
```

Comment: This will break on a single whitespace in a path, you should rather use `read`. Additionally the `bash` shell can do `dirname`'s work with parameter expansion: `while IFS='' read -r i || [[ -n "$i" ]]; do unzip -d ${i%/*} $i; done <outfile.txt`.

Comment: This still breaks when there's spaces in the path, even with @dessert's script